# Magento2: Remove Category path from product URL is not working for all products

Tags: magento2.2

I have a Magento2 store. I don't want to add the category path into products URLs for that I set “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” as "NO" in magento2 Admin, but It still add the category path in some products, not in all products. 
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Magento won’t update existing url rewrites but you could use a module like this one which is free. Also don’t forget to reindex and flush the cache.

https://github.com/experius/Magento2-Module-Experius-ReindexCatalogUrlRewrites

Comment: Hello, I´m trying to regenerate url with https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites but after do it all the urls are 404